# Is there a simpler way to control the intensity of text-shadow?

Tags: css

**Objective**
I need to intensify the text shadow effect.

**Current Solution**
According to MDN, the ["text-shadow ... accepts a comma-separated list of shadows"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow), so I just duplicated several layers of the same shadow:

```
.glow-triple {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px gold, 0 0 10px gold, 0 0 10px gold;
}
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/targumon/wdhLqjrh/ )

**My Question**
Is there a more concise way than this repetitious usage?

**Prior Research**
I found two other SO Q&As that touch this subject, but they don't address my specific question:

- [jquery dense text shadow and blurred background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869709/jquery-dense-text-shadow-and-blurred-background-color/17870173#17870173)
- [CSS: glowing text with glow very wide and high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673240/css-glowing-text-with-glow-very-wide-and-high/12673403#12673403)

***Edit***

Triggered by [badfilms' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766982/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-control-the-intensity-of-text-shadow/27767158#27767158), the *spread* keyword revealed another SO Q&A:

- [Browser support for text-shadow spread value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176129/browser-support-for-text-shadow-spread-value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `text-shadow` doesn't have the same properties as `box-shadow` (i.e. missing spread), we are forced to use your technique. You could potentially consider achieving this using other techniques, but I hardly believe they would be more concise.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the 'spread' keyword - I wonder why it's in the box-shadow spec, but not in the text-shadow spec. What other techniques do you have in your toolbox?